Is it possible to improve the ECPP test for the Wagstaff numbers $(2^q+1)/3$?
The Wagstaff numbers are $W_q = (2^q+1)/3$ with $q$ prime.
Today, the fastest way to prove that a Wagstaff number is prime is to use ECPP. However, details of the output of the Primo tool for testing $W_{167}$ and $W_{199}$ show that the Elliptic Curves used for proving that $W_{167}$ and $W_{199}$ are prime share some properties.
Here below are extracts from the output of Primo:
primo0 : (Ell_certif
      62357403192785191176690552862561408838653121833643
      9580401547
      ((6508850687193977087345831309080503843619,1)::nil)
      62357403192785191176690552862561408838653042598475
      271737008656
      0
      521284)
     ((Proof_certif _ H) :: nil)).
primo3 : (Ell_certif
      17188685859885937057412657
      137214140
      ((125269056526436611,1)::nil)
      17188685859885936978177489
      271737008656
      0
      521284)
     ((Proof_certif _ H) :: nil)).


- W199:  1569275433846670190958947355801916604025588861116008628225
primo0 : (Ell_certif
      267823007376498379256993682056860433753700498963798805883563
      122455
      ((2187113693818124039500172978297344444289583996102592993,1)::nil)
      267823007376498379256993682056860433753700498963798726648395
      271737008656
      0
      521284)
     ((Proof_certif _ H) :: nil)).

It shows that the same kind of curves is used: $y^2 = x^3 - a*x + 271737008656$ for $W_{167}$ and for $W_{199}$. The number $521284$ also appears 3 times.
The Wagstaff numbers are cousins of the Mersenne and Fermat numbers. And, like the 2 others, they have a lot of specific properties that make these numbers "special" and related to each others. So, my guess is that the ECPP mechanism could use specific Elliptic Curves rather than searching randomly for an appropriate EC. That should specialize and thus speed up the ECPP for these special numbers.
I do not master the EC and ECPP theory, and I'm looking for some help to see if some special EC are used when ECPP works on Wagstaff numbers. By The Way, I've already shown (experimentaly, up to $W_q$ prime with $q=141,079$ and for $W_q$ composite up to $q=14,479$) that the Denomme/Savin-Tsumura primality test for Fermat numbers based on Elliptic Curves does seem to work for the Wagstaff numbers :
$x_1=3 \text{ or } x_1=-1/3 \ , \   x_{j+1} = \frac{\displaystyle x_j^4+2x_j^2+1}{\displaystyle 4(x_j^3-x_j)}$
$\text{If } \ x_{q-1} \  \equiv \ -1/3 \ \pmod{W_q} \ ,$
$ \ \text{then } W_q = \frac{2^q+1}{3} \text{ is (PRobably) Prime}$ .
